# Stub a method on any instance of object

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

How can I stub a method of an object that is hardcoded in app? In rspec there is a method `allow_any_instance_of`.

I can't reverse the dependency, the initialisation of the object should still be hardcoded.

So, I have ClassA

```
namespace App
class ClassA
{
  public function doSomething(){
    // more code
    return($sth);
  }
}
```

It is used in ClassB

```
namespace App
class ClassB
{
 protected $instanceOfA;

 public function __construct(){
    $this->instnaceOfA = new ClassA();    
 }

 public function methodToTest(){
   $result = $this->instanceOfA->doSomething()
   // more code
 }
}
```

Comment: new ReflectionClass ?

Comment: From what I see, ReflectionClass reads info about a class, and I need to modify the class itself. I haven't done PHP in years.

Comment: post some code and i'll give an example

Comment: Added some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for? a plugable interface? if you change the classB to ClassA on line 33 it will switch to the other class.

```
Interface TheInterface
{
    public function doSomething();
}

class ClassA implements TheInterface
{
  public function doSomething(){
    echo __METHOD__;
  }
}

class ClassB implements TheInterface
{
  public function doSomething(){
    echo __METHOD__;
  }
}

class ClassProcess
{
 protected $instance;

 public function __construct(TheInterface $class){
    $this->instance = $class;    
 }

 public function methodToTest(){
   $this->instance->doSomething();
 }
}   

$process = new ClassProcess(new ClassB());
$process->methodToTest();
```

Comment: No, not exactly :)
I want to specify a response for an already initialised object. In Ruby&Python it's a few lines of code. It is even possible in PHP to modify a class so any already initialised instances of this class are modified as well?

Comment: @Michal core PHP cannot do that, even with reflection. It's not built for monkey patching, like Ruby. But if you really want to, you can use the runkit extension: http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php